# Load specific mongoose models first

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm attempting to use a model ("goal") in my "like" model class (Code below). However every time I startup the node instance it says that `Goal.findById` is not a function.

After running a console.log(*number*) in each model, I found that they load very oddly and out of the order I would like/need.

I was wondering how I can load models before others or set a specific load order for models?

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var User = require('../models/user.js');
var Goal = require('../models/goal.js');

var likeSchema = new Schema({
userPosted: {
    type: Number,
    ref: 'user',
    required: true
},
goal: {
  type: Number,
  ref: 'goal',
  required: true
}},
{
  timestamps: true
});

likeSchema.post('save', function (doc, next) {
    var goalID = doc.goal;

Goal.findOne({'_id': doc.goal}, function(err, goal) {
    goal.likes.push(doc._id);
    goal.save();
    User.findById(doc.userPosted, function(err, user) {
        user.likedPosts.push(goalID);
        user.save();
        next();
    });
});
});

likeSchema.post('remove', function(doc) {
  Goal.findById(doc.goal, function(err, goal) {
      goal.likes.pull(doc._id);
      goal.save();

      User.findById(doc.userPosted, function(err, user) {
        user.likedPosts.pull(goal._id);
        user.save();
      });
  });
});

console.log("4");

module.exports = mongoose.model('like', likeSchema);
```

Error:

```
TypeError: Goal.findOne is not a function at model.<anonymous> (E:\Project\like.js:28:10)
```

**Edit: ** goal.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var autoIncrement = require('mongoose-auto-increment');
var User = require('../models/user.js');
var Like = require('../models/like.js');

var goal = new Schema({
    user: {
        type: Number,
        ref: 'user',
        required: true
    },
    user_name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        default: undefined,
        trim: true
    },
    location: {
        type: String,
        default: undefined
    },
    likes: [{
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'like'
    }],
    comments: [{
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'comment'
    }],
    updates: [{
      type: Schema.ObjectId,
      ref: 'update'
    }],
    created: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    cover_image: {
        type: String,
        default: undefined
    },
    complete_by: {
        type: String,
        default: "Death"
    },
    completed: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    },
    completedDate: {
        type: String,
        default: undefined
    },
    url: {
        type: String,
        default: undefined
    },
    sponsor: {
      type: String,
      default: undefined
    },
    private: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    }
});

goal.plugin(autoIncrement.plugin, 'goal');

goal.pre('save', function (next) {
    this.wasNew = this.isNew;
    next();
});

goal.post('save', function (doc) {
    if (this.wasNew) {
        User.findById(doc.user, function (err, user) {
            user.goals.push(doc._id);
            user.save();
        });
    }
});

goal.post('remove', function(doc) {
  //TODO: Removes like objects/user profile/anything containing the goal
  User.findById(doc.user, function(err, user) {
      user.goals.pull(doc._id);
      user.save();
  });

  Like.find({
    'goal': doc._id
  }).remove(function(err, removed) {
    if(err) {
      console.log("ERROR?");
      return;
    }
    console.log('removed likes - ' + removed);
  });
});    

module.exports = mongoose.model('goal', goal);
```

Comment: Have you correctly 'exported' goal.js file as module?

Comment: @NidhinDavid oh yes. sorry I didn't include that but I have.

Comment: You need to make sure all models are defined before you try to use them. Can you show the code of goal.js?

Comment: @Molda added to post

Comment: What I think you should do is to define schemas then export models then add pre and post hooks to schemas, or don't even use hooks and instead create custom functions that do what you want .

Answer (score 0):

I think your `likeschema` would be something like this -

```
var likeSchema = new Schema({
userPosted: {
    type: Number,
    ref: 'User',
    required: true
},
goal: {
  type: Number,
  ref: 'Goal',
  required: true
}},
{
  timestamps: true
});
```

If it doesn't work, can you please show your code for `Goal` model?

Comment: The error is actually in the pre and post middlewares where it says Goal.findOne is not a function. I found this is because the Goal model hasn't been loaded yet.